# What does the value -1 mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

As pratice im doing a React search filter, i was able to complete it but a doubt remain:

```
const list = [
    "Banana",
    "Apple",
    "Orange",
    "Mango",
    "Pineapple",
    "Watermelon",
  ];
```

```
const filteredValues = list.filter((item) => {
      console.log(item.toLowerCase().e.target.value.toLowerCase());
      return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
    });
```

This is the logic for the filter, my question is: what does the "-1" mean?

Comment: That console.log line is an error....

Comment: @epascarello, that was just me trying to find out what the -1 was...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JS indexOf() will return an index of -1 if an element can't be found**.

It's the result of `String.prototype.indexOf()` (but also use in `Array.prototype.indexOf()`.

Basically your code says it will list item that its value has substring of the input value.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: You might want to link to `String.prototype.indexOf` as that’s what’s being used here, not the array method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf